# PHP imagejpeg only works when saving the image

Tags: php, image

I've got this strange situation going on. Imagejpeg is only working when I define a filename to which the image is going to be saved. The problem is that I don't want to save the image, I just want to show it.

This is my code:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$img    = imagecreatefromjpeg("./_test/test.jpg");
imagejpeg($img, null, 100);
```

That doesn't work, but if I just change the last line to:

```
imagejpeg($img, "./_test/blah.jpg", 100);
```

The image is being saved as it should be.

Doesn anyone have experiance with this problem and knows a solution?

Comment: Does it give you any output at all?

Comment: It gives me that "broken image" icon.

Comment: There may be a warning being outputted; comment out the `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` line and check.

Comment: Remove the line header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); to see what is the error and tell it maybe we can help.

Comment: Then I'm just getting the raw image data: "���7ŋm^��~Ӵ OZ��a�{x�FY�ٜMu�"

Comment: That is strange. And you can definitely view the file through the same browser when it's just saved to a path on the server?

Comment: Like you would open up an image in Notepad++

Comment: Yeah i just tried your code and it worked fine, but make sure imagecreatefromjpeg is reading from an actual file/directory that exists.

Comment: Well no, my mistake. I can't view the file in the browser when I save it. I can open and view the image at the location where it is saved on my computer. ( using localhost )

Comment: The file/directory does exist, because I can save the image and I can see it pop up in my Windows Explorer.

Comment: @Bart: No, I mean navigating to it directly though `localhost`. Do you get the same broken image? If you do... 1) try another browser 2) try another source image 3) try without the last two arguments 4) try with another image format

Comment: When I navigate to the image by using the absolute path in my browser, the image shows up just fine.

Comment: Also, when I define a filename, that save image is showing up just fine in my browser when navigating to it. I just can't show the image by setting the filename to NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your image script file stored as UTF8 instead of ANSI? If so, then that might be your problem. See this answer to an earlier similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3170007/123749

Answer (score -1):

Try this code to display the image, also you need image headers like so `header('Content-type: image/png');`
`imagejpeg($img);`

Comment: No. **jpeg !== png**

Comment: Content-type imge/png will display jpeg images!

Comment: Then you should explain this in your answer. And explain why use this header at all, as the OP already has the correct header for JPEG files.